# F# Equivalent to Enumerable.OfType<'a>

Tags: f#

**...or, how do I filter a sequence of classes by the interfaces they implement?**

Let's say I have a sequence of objects that inherit from Foo, a `seq<#Foo>`. In other words, my sequence will contain one or more of four different subclasses of Foo.

Each subclass implements a different independent interface that shares nothing with the interfaces implemented by the other subclasses.

Now I need to filter this sequence down to only the items that implement a particular interface.

The C# version is simple:

```
    void MergeFoosIntoList<T>(IEnumerable<Foo> allFoos, IList<T> dest) 
        where T : class
    {
        foreach (var foo in allFoos)
        {
            var castFoo = foo as T;
            if (castFoo != null)
            {
                dest.Add(castFoo);
            }
        }
    }
```

I could use LINQ from F#:

```
    let mergeFoosIntoList (foos:seq<#Foo>) (dest:IList<'a>) =
            System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<'a>(foos)
            |> Seq.iter dest.Add
```

However, I feel like there should be a more idiomatic way to accomplish it. I thought this would work...

```
    let mergeFoosIntoList (foos:seq<#Foo>) (dest:IList<'a>) =
            foos
            |> Seq.choose (function | :? 'a as x -> Some(x) | _ -> None)
            |> Seq.iter dest.Add
```

However, the complier complains about `:? 'a` - telling me:

> This runtime coercion or type test from type     'b      to      'a     involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed.

I can't figure out what further type annotations to add. There's no relationship between the interface `'a` and `#Foo` except that one or more subclasses of Foo implement that interface. Also, there's no relationship between the different interfaces that can be passed in as `'a` except that they are all implemented by subclasses of Foo.

I eagerly anticipate smacking myself in the head as soon as one of you kind people points out the obvious thing I've been missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically just adding a 'box' is sufficient (e.g. change `function` to `fun x -> match box x with`), but let me try it out...

Yeah; basically you cannot sideways cast from one arbitrary generic type to another, but you can upcast to System.Object (via `box`) and then downcast to anything you like:

```
type Animal() = class end
type Dog() = inherit Animal()
type Cat() = inherit Animal()

let pets : Animal list = 
    [Dog(); Cat(); Dog(); Cat(); Dog()]
printfn "%A" pets

open System.Collections.Generic     

let mergeIntoList (pets:seq<#Animal>) (dest:IList<'a>) = 
    pets 
    |> Seq.choose (fun p -> match box p with  
                            | :? 'a as x -> Some(x) | _ -> None) //'
    |> Seq.iter dest.Add 

let l = new List<Dog>()
mergeIntoList pets l
l |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Comment: @Brian - but would you go this route? In this case, OfType seems a lot prettier...

Comment: If it's just a matter of syntax and not performance, it would be easy enough to extend the Seq module with an `ofType<'a>` function. Then the method body would just be: `pets |> Seq.ofType<'a> |> Seq.iter dest.Add`

Comment: Enumerable.OfType is shorter, and "shortest" is commonly a proxy for "preferred/best" for me.  I was just answering the question.  (Enumerable.OfType also assumes a dependency on .NET 3.5 or above.)

Answer (score 11):

You can do this:

```
let foos = candidates |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x :? Foo) |> Seq.cast<Foo>
```

Comment: `let ofType<'a> (items: _ seq) = items |> Seq.filter(fun x -> x :? 'a) |> Seq.cast<'a>` gives me *This runtime coercion or type test from type 'b to 'a involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed.* I think in my current context the `box x` is needed

Comment: adding another cast it works: ``let ofType<'a> (items: _ seq) = items |> Seq.cast<obj> |> Seq.filter(fun x -> x :? 'a) |> Seq.cast<'a>\

Answer (score 2):

From https://gist.github.com/kos59125/3780229

```
let ofType<'a> (source : System.Collections.IEnumerable) : seq<'a> =
   let resultType = typeof<'a>
   seq {
      for item in source do
         match item with
            | null -> ()
            | _ ->
               if resultType.IsAssignableFrom (item.GetType ())
               then
                  yield (downcast item)
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option for those inclined:

```
Module Seq = 
    let ofType<'a> (items: _ seq)= items |> Seq.choose(fun i -> match box i with | :? 'a as a -> Some a |_ -> None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source library available on nuget, [FSharp.Interop.Compose](http://jbtule.github.io/FSharp.Interop.Compose/)

That Converts most `Linq` methods into a [idomatic F# form](https://github.com/jbtule/FSharp.Interop.Compose/blob/master/src/NET45/FSharp.Interop.Compose.Linq/Enumerable.fsx#L74). Including `OfType`

**Test Case:**

```
[<Fact>]
let ofType () =
   let list = System.Collections.ArrayList()
   list.Add(1) |> ignore
   list.Add("2") |> ignore
   list.Add(3) |> ignore
   list.Add("4") |> ignore
   list
       |> Enumerable.ofType<int>
       |> Seq.toList |> should equal [1;3]
```