# Filter by constraint

Tags: f#, type-constraints

Ok, I realise this might be a weird question. But I need to ask it anyway. It goes as follows:

Suppose I have something like the following:

```
type Foo() =
    member this.MyFooFun i = 2*i

type Bar() =
    inherit Foo()
    member this.MyBarFun i = 3*i

type Baz() =
    inherit Foo()
    member this.MyBazFun i = 5*i

type FooSeq = seq<Foo>
```

What I want to do, is to filter out all the Foo's from a FooSeq that has the member MyBarFun. Is it possible to do anything like that?

I realise I will probably have to use the `:?` operator to check whether each element is a `Bar`, but as I said - I have to ask. The reason I would rather not do this, is that the types corresponding to `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` lies in a library developed somewhere else in the company. And there might be added more types containing the `MyBarFun`-member at any given time.

Comment: It would make your life easier if all the subtypes with a `MyBarFun` could be via an intermediate type, or implementing an interface such as `IMyBarFun`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2521254/126014

Comment: Please consider telling us some details about the actual problem you are trying to solve. While people may find direct answer for your question, it is very possible that by knowing the "big picture", the entire problem gets nice and straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to filter on the subtype, it's easy:

```
let foos = candidates |> Seq.filter (fun x -> not (x :? Bar))
```

If you explicitly want to filter away types that have a member called "MyBarFun", you'll need to use reflection:

```
let foos' =
    candidates
    |> Seq.filter (fun x ->
        not (x.GetType().GetMembers() |> Array.exists (fun m ->
            m.Name = "MyBarFun")))
```

Comment: I want to filter types that have a member called `MyBarFun` (such that they are the only ones left). And then I want to call them using `Seq.map`. As I expected, I will have to do this using reflection, since `MyBarFun` is not abstracted away into an interface. Thanks.:)